# Parse-AWS-S3 configuration issue

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Thanks for all the input and answers it has helped me alot with my migration from Parse to AWS BS. However, I still have a couple of issues I can't seem to find answers for...or at least that I can understand to act upon. So any help would be appreciated.

Using the below changes to the index.js I can access access the AWS ParseDB/MongoDB and I can upload and retrieve images and display pre and post migration images (have not finalized the migration).

This is just base changes with the fileKey added which I assume is why I can see my pre migration images. But when I change the index.js to include the S3 items as the instructions detail I get an error about data not being formatted correctly just by building the app. Next section below

Working Index.js without S3:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI

if (!databaseUri) {
console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://accessID:accessPassword@dsxxxxx.mlab.com:xxxx/parse-aws',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'AppID',
fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY || 'fileKey',
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'masterkey'
});
```

This is the changes to the index.js I made for using S3 bucket to store my images.

Revised Index.js to use S3:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI

if (!databaseUri) {
console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://accessID:password@dsxxxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx/parse-aws',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'AppID',
fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY || 'FileKey,
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MasterKey'
filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
'myaccess key', 'secret key', 'bucket' {directAccess: true}),

});
```

After deploying this configuration and then trying to access my app which has no issues using the first version of the index.js above I get the following errors/messages.

Build and Run App in xcode I get this error
[Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

If I try to login to the app, I get the error message (Data could not be read because it is in the wrong format)

Nothing is different in my AppDelegate between the two...and if I redeploy the first Index.js I have no issues and no S3.

The last question (if I get the above to work) is How Do I Get All the Pre-Migration Images from Parse into my bucket so that all the images are in the same location and I am not using the MongoDB 
GridStore.

Thanks in advance for any help
PS All the correct accessKeys, secretKeys, fileKeys etc are in both the index.js and in the AWS BeanStalk Dashboard's Environment configurations sections...all the S3 items are there even if I use the plain index.js that works.  So it has to be something in the S3 extended index.js.
Thanks

UPDATE
Thank you!...I did fix that issue (comma after MasterKey) and removed the comma after {directAccess: true}) logs are barking at filesAdapter below

but it still loads the environment and when I try and access with my app I get the following error in Xcode when I build and run

`

```
/var/app/current/index.js:19
filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
at startup (node.js:136:18)
at node.js:966:3

npm ERR! Linux 4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.3.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.3.0
npm ERR! npm v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.0.0 start: node index.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.0.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

`

[Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: after the line masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MasterKey' there should be a comma and you dont need the comma after the {directAccess: true})

Comment: thanks...updated with new error

Comment: your index JS looks kind of weird, try to build it like this guy https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/961

Comment: Thanks.  I have checked my index.js to the version you reference and there is no differences.  I had the correct syntax for the .S3Adapter that was his error but like for line the rest of the code, functions, commas and semicolons are the same.  I just don't understand why it is complaining about filesAdapter in the error or why it is saying that there could be something wrong with the parse-server-example package.

Comment: I prefer using the parse-server and not the example. I dont understand the difference between them but the regular parse-server with environment variables works awesome...

Comment: Thanks....I had tried to load the parse-server but it didn't seem to take and the pages with the "button" install only use the example.  Not sure how to "upgrade" the parse version in beanstalk or if I have to try and create a new environment/application and try to get the Parse-Server to load.  I have pulled it from Git...  How did you install the full package?  thanks for all your comments

Comment: I am using VPS with Ubuntu and you can install Parse server with just this command "sudo npm install -g parse-server"

Comment: you also need to have npm installed and mongodb but all of them are very easy to install, I am also from Europe and AWS prices are very different than the one in US

Comment: thanks very much....I have npm installed so I will try your suggestions.